Python FileNotFoundError when loading JSON config file
I'm currently working on a Python project where I need to load a JSON configuration file. I'm using the following function to load the JSON file:
def load_config(self, file_path):    
    try:    
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:    
            data = json.load(file)    
            self.config_data.update(data)    
    except FileNotFoundError:    
        print(f"File not found: {file_path}")    
    except json.JSONDecodeError:    
        print(f"Invalid JSON format: {file_path}")    

However, when I attempt to load my JSON file located at 'defmet_common/configs/config.edi_db_servers.json', I keep encountering a FileNotFoundError.
Interestingly, when I copy the relative path of the file from my file explorer, I get 'defmet_common\configs\config.edi.db_servers.json' which uses backslashes and seems to have a different file extension.
I have verified that the file does exist at the specified location and has the .json extension. I'm running the script from the same directory that contains the defmet_common folder.
Why am I encountering this issue and how can I resolve it?

defmet_common/configs/config.edi_db_servers.json and defmet_common\configs\config.edi.db_servers.json are two different filepaths because of the _ vs. . before db_servers. Also, is edi.db_servers meant to be directories or part of the file extension? If it is meant to be directories you should do defmet_common/configs/config/edi/db_servers.json.
Both of the filepaths point to a file in defmet_common/configs but the first points to a file that has the filename config.edi_db_servers.json while the second points to the file, config.edi.db_servers.json.
Review your filename and path. Nested directories should be separated by slashes followed by the whole filename including the exact file extension (.edi.db_servers.json or whatever yours says).
